# MvvmCross actual SQLite plugin to use in .NET Standard project

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross, .net-standard

I am developing an app with **.NET Standard 2.0** project as core project, so bumped into the fact, that I am not sure how I should (can) handle the famous easy-to-access-and-setup approach with **MvvmCross**.

Search for `Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite` plugin in Nuget doesn't return anything (apparently it's been a while and it's not supported).

[SQLite-PCL](https://mvvmcross.readme.io/v4.4/docs/sqlite-pcl) doesn't seem like sound `.NET Standard`-ish, plus there is a whole bunch of different packages with similar name (and with no any close reference to MvvmCross actually) appear.

There is also [a reference to sqlite-pcl-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) plugin in release notes for MvvmCross 5, but it also "doesn't smell" `Mvx`-y.

So, what's going on with **MvvmCross SQLite** these days? What should I use? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be an official MvvmCross Plugin for SQLite but it was [dropped](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1518) sometime around early 2017 because the plugin was redundant. SQLite is probably the most popular database used in MvvmCross applications, but there is nothing in MvvmCross requiring this. You are still free to use Realm, Entity Framework Core, etc.

You should be using the [praeclarum/sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) version of SQLite since Android 7.0. Here is the [NuGet feed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) for the package. This version supports .NET Standard and PCL. Other forks are not maintained as much, or stopped working reliably on Android due to the changes to the way SQLite was changed in Android 7.0.

I've also recently provided another answer to a question asking how to add SQLite to an MvvmCross application since the plugin was removed. I provided some sample code for Android in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47103105/186046). The old MvvmCross SQLite Plugin [source code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/b830ab5189323b2ff9059e08ba359b4956709889/MvvmCross-Plugins/SQLite-PCL) is also still available.

Comment: Yeah. So, this isn't actually a clear, why you are mentioning that "...there is nothing in MvvmCross requiring this", as the previous plugin allowed to handle the database initialization transparently without a need to create a separate plugin per every platform. (What it actually does for all its other functionality). This was actually **the core** of my question.

Comment: The only questions I see you asking are: "What's going on with MvvmCross SQLite these days? What should I use? Any ideas?". All 3 questions have been addressed in my answer. The sentence "SQLite is probably the most popular database used in MvvmCross applications, but there is nothing in MvvmCross requiring this" is intended to communicate there is no relationship between the two libraries.

Comment: Well, I would not ask that question here, as the "classic" approach with SQLite (like initializing the databases separately per each platform) is widely known. This is the same talk as building plugins for accessing camera per every system, about defining separate http client per every platform. So one of the main features of MvvmCross (what appears even from this name) is ability to make things "cross-platform". That's why I am wandering, why it's not possible to have it real cross-platform stuff with SQLite and why MvvmCross now has nothing to do with that?